# vee-validate + vuetify text input field → how to migrate to new versions?

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js, vee-validate

I have a legacy `Vue2` code for login page. A part of it that is checking for username input field:

```html
...
<validation-observer ref="ref-id" v-slot="{ invalid }">
  <v-form>
    <v-card-text>
      <validation-provider
        v-slot="{ errors }"
        rules="rulename"
        name="username"
      >
        <v-text-field
          v-model="input.username"
          label="username"
          prepend-icon="mdi-account-circle"
          :error-messages="errors"
        ></v-text-field>
      </validation-provider>
      ...
    </v-card-text>
  </v-form>
</validation-observer>
...
```

Now I'm trying to create same code using new versions `Vuetify` and `vee-validate` (`3` and `4`)

I'm able to create `v-text-field` with new version of `Vuetify`:

```html
<vee-validation-form as="v-form">
  <v-card-text>
    <!-- <vee-validation-field as="v-text-field" -->
    <v-text-field
      v-model="input.username"
      label="username"
      prepend-icon="mdi-account-circle"
      :error-messages="errors"
    ></v-text-field>
    <!-- ></vee-validation-field> -->
  </v-card-text>
</vee-validation-form>
```

Where

- `vee-validation-form` is a [`Form`](https://vee-validate.logaretm.com/v4/api/form/)
- `vee-validation-field` is a [`Field`](https://vee-validate.logaretm.com/v4/api/field/)

And this code is at least displaying `username` input element.

But when I'm trying to use `<vee-validation-field as="v-text-field"` instead of `<v-text-field` it shows me error:

```
ERROR
Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'split')
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'split')
    at normalizeFormPath (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/vee-validate/dist/vee-validate.esm.js:100:26)
    at ReactiveEffect.eval [as fn] (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/vee-validate/dist/vee-validate.esm.js:1603:70)
    at ReactiveEffect.run (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/@vue/reactivity/dist/reactivity.esm-bundler.js:217:19)
    at get value [as value] (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/@vue/reactivity/dist/reactivity.esm-bundler.js:1178:33)
    at unref (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/@vue/reactivity/dist/reactivity.esm-bundler.js:1057:29)
    at _useFieldValue (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/vee-validate/dist/vee-validate.esm.js:1141:70)
    at useFieldState (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/vee-validate/dist/vee-validate.esm.js:1044:54)
    at _useField (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/vee-validate/dist/vee-validate.esm.js:1618:72)
    at useField (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/vee-validate/dist/vee-validate.esm.js:1597:12)
    at setup (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/vee-validate/dist/vee-validate.esm.js:2038:164)
```

**The question is:** how to use `v-text-field` component with `vee-validate`? As I understand correctly here is no `ValidationObserver` and `ValidationPbserver` components in new `vee-validate v4`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Field component expects a `name` attribute, the error is thrown when it tries to call `split()` on the value. Just set a name and the error is gone:

```html
<Field as="v-text-field" 
  name="username"
  ...
></Field>
```

---

However, `label` is a prop of the `Field` component, but it only passes attrs (i.e. non-props) to the custom input component (see [code](https://github.com/logaretm/vee-validate/blob/8edc3975038c67e8c503949fd1da92e12e5e5f55/packages/vee-validate/src/Field.ts#L255-L256)), so you cannot pass a label to the v-text-field. Also, you would have to get the error messages through the form.

Looks like using `:as` is more trouble than solution at the moment. Probably better to stick with the slot:

```html
<vee-validation-field
  v-slot="{ field, errors }"
  name="username"
  rules="required|needsL"
  v-model="username"
>
  <v-text-field
    v-model="field.value"
    v-bind="field"
    label="username"
    prepend-icon="mdi-account-circle"
    :error-messages="errors"
  />
</vee-validation-field>
```

(the somewhat duplicated `v-bind` and `v-model` on the VTextField is necessary for them moment due to an [issue in vee-validate](https://github.com/logaretm/vee-validate/issues/4182))

```js
const { createApp, ref } = Vue;
const { createVuetify } = Vuetify
const vuetify = createVuetify()

VeeValidate.defineRule('required', VeeValidateRules.required)
VeeValidate.defineRule('needsL', v => v.toLowerCase().includes('L') || 'Input something with an `l`')

const app = {
  components: {
    'vee-validation-form': VeeValidate.Form,
    'vee-validation-field': VeeValidate.Field,
  },
  setup(){
    return {
      username1: ref('user 1'),
      username2: ref('user 2'),
    }
  }

}
createApp(app).use(vuetify).mount('#app')
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@3/dist/vuetify.min.css" />
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@mdi/font@5.x/css/materialdesignicons.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<div id="app">
  <v-app>
    <v-main>
      <vee-validation-form as="v-form" v-slot="{errors}">
        <v-card-text>
        Field from :as
          <vee-validation-field as="v-text-field" 
            name="username1"
            v-model="username1"
            prepend-icon="mdi-account-circle"
            :error-messages="errors.username1"
            rules="required|needsL"
          ></vee-validation-field>
          
          Field in slot
          <vee-validation-field
            v-slot="{ field, errors }"
            v-model="username2"
            name="username2"
            rules="required|needsL"
          >
            <v-text-field
              v-model="field.value"
              v-bind="field"
              label="username"
              prepend-icon="mdi-account-circle"
              :error-messages="errors"
            />
          </vee-validation-field>
          
        </v-card-text>
      </vee-validation-form>

    </v-main>
  </v-app>
</div>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3/dist/vue.global.prod.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@3/dist/vuetify.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vee-validate/4.10.8/vee-validate.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@vee-validate/rules@4.11.0/dist/vee-validate-rules.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Yes but, no. `name="username"` is solving error, but [`label="username"`](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/text-fields/#hints-26-messages) is not visible in the snippet (also not sure if validation also works correctly). Not sure if it possible to use `vee-validation-field as="v-text-field"` construction at all...

Comment: Yes, you are right, `label` is not passed to the custom input component. Validation works, but you have to get the errors from the form. Have a look at the updated answer. I agree, using `:as` is currently not working very well

Comment: Nice. Much better. But still does not work correctly. I don't understand how it works and what happens inside, but if you remove first `Field from :as` component, the second `v-text-field` will stop work too (no validation happens) `(0_o)` I can't figure out how `username: ref(),` acts, but probably it will be better to add `v-bind="field"` property inside `v-text-field` (also I don't understand why its name should be exactly `field`) tag instead of using global reference

Comment: Right, yes, it is even more annoying... sorry for the iterative answer. Have a look at the updated answer

Answer (score 0):

Overall, the approach described above is correct, but a significant mistake has been made.

Just a week ago, I had to deal with migrating our large project, which has a vast number of forms, from Vuetify 2 to 3 and from Vee-validate 3 to 4. Here's what I'd like to suggest after spending a considerable amount of time studying the issue and dealing with specific cases. I won't inherit from the previous answer but will outline my entire solution in one message, making it convenient for those seeking an answer to grasp the topic immediately.

When determining the validation-observer and validation-provider components, everything is accurate. In my case, In my case, I registered the **Form** components and **Field** named  and . For those migrating a real project, this will save a lot of time, avoiding the need to rewrite component names.

```
app
.component('validation-observer', Form)
.component('validation-provider', Field)
```

Now, we should perceive the Field component as the primary input component, and v-text-field simply as a visual object that will merely exchange data with Field, which is now the validation-provider.

Based on the documentation, we can interact with the validation-provider and our field through a slot, but not the **field**, but the **componentField**. It will contain the correct object with the **modelValue** key instead of **value**, allowing us to correctly access the component's value. This ensures proper compatibility with Vue 3 since value was used in the 2 version. Hence, the use of the **as** parameter is unnecessary by default. The Field component, containing the inner component, doesn't display as a standard input field, and we utilize the **componentField** slot through **v-bind** in our input component.

So we need to take 2 actions:

1. Move **v-model** to the **Field** component
2. Add **v-bind** to our input field

Here is an example of the correct code (Use your component names if required):

```
<validation-observer
    v-slot="{ handleSubmit }"
>
   <validation-provider
            v-slot="{ componentField, errors }"
            v-model="input.username"
            name="Username"
            rules="required"
        >
    <v-text-field
      v-bind="componentField"
      :error-messages="errors"
      label="Username"
      prepend-icon="mdi-account-circle"
    />
    </validation-provider>
</validation-observer>
```

Now our field is correctly synchronized with the validation component Field (validation-provider).

**For Field(validation-observer) slots, see the [documentation](https://vee-validate.logaretm.com/v4/api/form/).**